# haar classifiers exchange

Tags: opencv, download, exchange-server, classification

I found just one topic about this from 2010 and wonder if there is now any website or place where people can download free or buy trained clasiffiers for haar detection. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify which topic you have found. Are you speaking of this [site](http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34)? This is from before 2010, but this is the only I have found...

Comment: Hi, it was just a question here on stackoverflow someone asking for same thing, don't have reference by hand, the question was not suttisfied.
Actually yes, thanks fro link, these listed there are all included in openCV library itself. Lookign for a bit larger marketplace or exchange.

Comment: Ops, I forgot that those cascades went with the new versions of OpenCV, because in previous versions (I don't remember which), the only cascades availables were the faces. Anyway, I hope that you find and if possible, share with us :) Ask in the opencv forum too.